# Why does my React child component not re-render when an array passed down in props is updated after data fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

My parent component (Profile.js) fetches the activity data of a user specified in the url parameter, then updates the profileActivity state. This state is then passed down to my child component (ProfileActivity.js) where it should be rendered.

However, the child component (ProfileActivity.js) does not render the newly fetched data straight away, and only does so if I interact with the page, e.g. by pressing a button.

I've tried to use the spread operator when calling setProfileActivity(activity) in order to make things immutable, but this does not seem to have any effect, though I think this could still be the issue so perhaps I'm doing something wrong? I've also used a key={} on the component, but this again does not seem to do anything.

What do I need to do to trigger ProfileActivity.js to update as soon as setProfileActivity(activity) is called with the new data?

Profile.js

```
function Profile(props) {
  const {parameter1} = props.match.params;
  const [profileViewing, setProfileViewing] = useState(null);
  const [profileDetails, setProfileDetails] = useState(null);
  const [profileActivity, setProfileActivity] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  // When URL parameters change, determine which profile to show
  useEffect(() => {
    if(parameter1) {
      setProfileViewing(parameter1);
    }
  }, [props, parameter1]);

  // When the profile being viewed (profileViewing state) changes, fetch and store the viewed profile's details and activity
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchProfileDetailsAndActivity(username) {
      try {
        const profile = await getUserDetailsFromUsername(username);
        setProfileDetails(profile);
        const activity = await 
        getActivityArray(profile.latestActivity);
        setProfileActivity(activity);
      } catch(error) {
        // Handle error
      }  
    }

    if(profileViewing) {
      fetchProfileDetailsAndActivity(profileViewing);
    }
  }, [profileViewing])

  // If profileDetails and profileActivity are no longer null, set loading to false
  useEffect(() => {
    if(profileDetails && profileActivity) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }, [profileDetails, profileActivity])

    return(
      <div className="Profile">
        <main>
          <div className="wrap">
            <div className="dual-right">
              <ProfileActivity profileDetails={profileDetails} profileActivity={profileActivity} loading={loading}/>
            </div>    
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    )
}

export default Profile;
```

ProfileActivity.js

```
const ProfileActivity = (props) => {
  const getActivityList = () => {
    let listItems = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < props.profileActivity.length; i++) {
      console.log(props.profileActivity[i])
      listItems.push(
        <p key={props.profileActivity[i].id}>Item {props.profileActivity[i].id}</p>
      )
    }

    return listItems;
  }

  if(props.loading) {
    return(
      <div className="box">
        <h3>Latest Activity</h3>   
        <div class="lds-ellipsis"><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div></div> 
      </div>
    )
  } else {
    return(
      <div className="box">
        <h3>Latest Activity</h3>   
          <ul>
            {getActivityList()} 
          </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ProfileActivity;
```

An example of the data returned from getUserDetailsFromUsername('somename'):

```
{ createdOn: it {
    seconds: 1635703629, 
    nanoseconds: 60000000
  },
  email: "somename@address.com",
  latestActivity: [
    0: "FEnZZBcQph0oPtoOQErQ"
    1: "PuRQVS1OuRQNv42wCrlk" ],
  username: "somename" }
```

I then pass the latestActivity array to getActivityArray(array), which takes the array of reference IDs and searches another database with them, fills a new array with the richer details, and returns this new array. An example of a returned array with 1 activity:

```
[{ date: 1636129735609, 
   refs: { artist: "Rihanna"
           songID: "Gt8xVxzc9badIuEy0td1"
           title: "Umbrella" }, 
   type: 'addSong', 
   uid: 'ZvDymG7poeNw8MmIaA2hIONInA83', 
   id: 'FEnZZBcQph0oPtoOQErQ' }]
```

Comment: Not your actual question, but can't `toRender.map(item => item)` be just `toRender`?

Comment: The `useEffect` hook is missing dependency array. Is this intentional? It also sort of looks like some of your logic *depends* on other previously set state in the same effect callback. If such interdependencies exist try splitting the logic up into several `useEffect` hooks with appropriate dependencies.

Comment: Could you perhaps reduce this to a minimal, reproducible code? That way, it will yield more answers(people don't wanna read all that code). A bonus with this is when you try to  create a reproducible code, most of the time you'll figure out the solution by yourself.

Comment: Thanks, taken comments on board and edited post with simplified code/clarified question. I should also mention that I have tried a useEffect() hook in ProfileActivity.js that checks for changes in props.profileActivity, and a console.log(props.profileActivity) does shows the array featuring the fetched data. However, when I try to iterate on it it does not work, because the array length is supposedly 0 (despite the console.log listing 1+ values). I can’t figure out what’s wrong, and have now simply removed any useEffect() hooks from ProfileActivity, still to no avail.

Comment: Updated again with example data returned from both fetch functions, and removed further unnecessary code. Could it be down to mutability when calling setProfileActivity(activity)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue in the end - the problem was in the getActivityArray() function and not to do with React.

I was searching the database in an inefficient way, by iteratively going over each ID in the array given as the parameter, and getting the relevant details with a single getDoc() query each time.

I replaced this with a Firebase getDocs() query which instead simply searches the collection for activity items matching the uid of the user whose profile has been requested.

Not sure why I didn't just do this in the first place as it makes a lot more sense, but lesson definitely learnt and time definitely wasted trying to diagnose the problem!